# Google Official API to Page Rank

Tags: google-api, pagerank

I am using "Open SEO stats Plugin" to check the page rank of any domain. I have also a custom google script which shows page rank in google sheets. It seems "toolbarqueries not working" (). Can anyone suggest any other sources where I can get the official page rank other than hitting "http://toolbarqueries.google.com/tbr"

Answer (score 2):

Google has [removed external PageRank access](http://searchengineland.com/google-has-confirmed-they-are-removing-toolbar-pagerank-244230). There is no longer a method to get it.